# Non-negative integrable functions converging in measure on $[0,1]$ with $ \lim_{k\to\infty}\int_0^1 f_k(x)dx=\int_0^1 f(x)dx .$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Suppose $\{f_k(x)\}$ is a sequence of nonnegative integrable functions on $[0,1]$, and $f_k(x)$ converges to $f(x)$ in measure on $[0,1]$. Suppose, in addition, that
>   $$ \lim_{k\to\infty}\int_0^1 f_k(x)dx=\int_0^1 f(x)dx .$$
>   Prove that for any measurable subset $E$ of $[0,1]$,
>   $$ \lim_{k\to\infty}\int_E f_k(x)dx=\int_E f(x)dx .$$

---

My attempt:

Since $f_k(x)$ converges to $f(x)$ in measure, we can select a subsequence $\{f_{k_i}\}$ such that $f_{k_i}$ converges to $f(x)$ almost everywhere. Now by Fatou's lemma, we have
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 f(x)dx&=\int_0^1\lim_{k_i\to\infty}f_{k_i}(x)dx\\
&\le\varliminf_{k_i\to\infty}\int_E f_{k_i}(x)dx+\varliminf_{k_i\to\infty}\int_{[0,1]\setminus E} f_{k_i}(x)dx\\
&\le\varliminf_{k_i\to\infty}\int_0^1 f_{k_i}(x)dx\\
&=\int_0^1 f(x)dx
\end{align}
 by the condition that $ \lim_{k\to\infty}\int_0^1 f_k(x)dx=\int_0^1 f(x)dx $. Hence, it follows that
$$ \lim_{k_i\to\infty}\int_E f_{k_i}(x)dx=\int_E f(x)dx .$$
But now I get stuck in proving the limit is also correct for $f_k$, not just a subsequence of it. Any idea is appreciated. Thanks.

---

**Edit**:

I think the question missed a hypothesis that $f\in L^1([0,1])$ which plays a vital role in the proof. Otherwise, we can construct a nice counterexample like the one discussed in the comment provided by Sangchul Lee.

Comment: Without the integrability of $f$, the conclusion may be false. In other words, there are counter-examples when $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\infty$.

Comment: The proof below works only when $f$ is integrable, in which case no mass escapes towards $+\infty$ and thus convergence improves to $L^1$. But if $f$ is not integrable, it is no more the case. As for a counter-example, consider $$ f_k(x) = \frac{1}{x}\mathbf{1}_{[1/k,1/2]}(x) + k\mathbf{1}_{[1-1/k,1]}(x), \qquad f(x) = \frac{1}{x}\mathbf{1}_{(0,1/2]}(x). $$ Then $f_k \to f$ in measure (because $f_k \to f$ a.e.) and $\int_{0}^{1}f_k(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\to\infty=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$, but $$\int_{[1/2,1]}f_k(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=1 \neq 0 = \int_{[1/2,1]}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.$$

Comment: The last part of my comment implies that, for $(f_k)_{k\geq 1}$ and $f$ defined as above and for $E=[1/2, 1]$, we have $$\lim_{k\to\infty} \int_E f_k(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = 1 \neq 0 = \int_E f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x, $$since $\int_E f_k(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = 1$ identically for any $k \geq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that for some measurable $E \subseteq[0,1]$ we have

$$\int_E f_k \not\to \int_E f$$

Then there is $\varepsilon > 0$ and a subsequence $(f_{p(k)})_k$ such that $$\left|\int_E f - \int_E f_{p(k)}\right| \ge \varepsilon, \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$$

$f_{p(k)} \to f$ in measure so there exists a further subsequence $(f_{p(q(k))})_k$ which converges to $f$ a.e.

However, in the comments you claimed that you proved the statement when you have convergence a.e. so it follows

$$\int_E f_{p(q(k))} \to \int_E f$$

which is a contradiction with the fact that the difference is bounded from below by $\varepsilon$.